# Angular dataSource doesn't sort

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, datasource

I'm trying to make header names into clickable sorting buttons.
From what I understand of the code, it gains data from "projects".
After following different tutorials, I presume I have to replace "projects" with a sorted datasource in order to sort data. Because of that, I tried making a sorted datasource using "projects".

When I type projects into new `MatTableDataSource` it turns into `this.projects` and it gives me this error:

> Argument of type 'Record<string, Project>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Project[]'.
> Type 'Record<string, Project>' is missing the following properties from type 'Project[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2345)
> (property) ProjectsComponent.projects: Record<string, Project>

Can anybody give me advise? My classmate thinks the error means that `MatTableDataSource` doesn't know what's inside projects. But I don't know what to do about that.

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="newProjectForm" (ngSubmit)="addProject()" *ngIf="projects">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="projects | keyvalue " matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
<ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
```

TS

```
  public projects !: Record<string, Project>;
  public previousProjects !: Record<string, Project>;
  public columns = ['Name', 'Intermediaries', 'Client', 'Address', 'Contact', 'ContactEmail', 'Billable', 'NeedsRemark', 'Delete'];
  public submitting : boolean = false;
  
//Needs to contain projects inside. I don't know how to insert it properly yet.
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();


 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

Examples of tutorials that I tried:
https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSt9CI3BXv4&t=1321s

Edit: I think I get projects from a dbService and the dbService receive data from an inputFieldTemplate in the HTML.

Comment: How do you get your projects? Is it an API call?

Comment: Can you also include the `Post` interface/class?

Comment: I think I get projects from a dbService and the dbService receive data from an inputFieldTemplate in the HTML.

Comment: Rather than adding details in comments, please [edit] your question to add requested information. You can then comment saying that you have done so. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice.  Editing updates into your question ensures that they don't get lost and that everybody who wants to answer the question sees them.